# Rounding float numbers TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

Why isn't working, i got the error : TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

My code

```
qtyprice = 0.5221932114882507
lot_size = 0.1

quantity = float(round(qtyprice, lot_size))
print (quantity)
```

My expected result should be 0.5

When i try this way, the result is 0

```
qtyprice = 0.5221932114882507
lot_size = 0.1
qtyprice = int(qtyprice)
lot_size = int(lot_size)
quantity = float(round(qtyprice, lot_size))
print (quantity)
```

Comment: Change `lot_size` to 1. The second parameter in `round` is how many decimal digits to have, it should be a positive int.

Comment: round(number, digits) - `number:  Required. The number to be rounded` - `digits: Optional. The number of decimals to use when rounding the number. Default is 0`

Comment: sometimes the lot size is 0.01, my output would be 0.52, so how to do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second parameter of `round` is the number of digits after the decimal point you want to "keep" after rounding your number,
this number should be an int and in your case should be 1

this should do the trick :

```
qtyprice = 0.5221932114882507
lot_size = 1 #what i changed 

quantity = float(round(qtyprice, lot_size))
print (quantity)
```

output:

```
0.5
```

Comment: sometimes the lot size is 0.01, my output would be 0.52, so how to do in this case?

Comment: I would change `lot_size ` to be 2 (since you want to keep 2 digits after the decimal point)